# Reset Flickity back to slide 1

Tags: jquery, flickity

I'm trying to reset my slider back to the first slide after 10 seconds of inactivity. The way I went about it does kick the slide back to slide 1 but when I go to slide to the next slide it kicks back up to the previous next slide instead of slide 2.

I've tried handling it mostly by changing the css attributes which does bring it back to slide 1 but does not clear the next slide to start fresh from 1

You can view my code on the following pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yZvOGJ

```
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {

        clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        idleState = false;

        idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 

            // Idle Event
          $("div.flickity-slider").attr({
              style: "transform: translateX(0%);"
            });
          $("div.carousel-cell:not(:first)").removeClass("is-selected").attr("aria-hidden", "true");
          $("div.carousel-cell:first").addClass("is-selected").attr("aria-hidden","false" );



            idleState = true; }, idleWait);
    });

    $("body").trigger("mousemove");

});
```

I've tried looking through the events section on the flickity site but I'm having trouble putting 2 and 2 together. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after some coffee and some more trial and error; I'll post the answer instead of deleting my question incase anyone else runs into the problem.

```
// external js: flickity.pkgd.js
idleTimer = null;
idleState = false;
idleWait = 2000;



$(document).ready(function () {

    $('*').bind('mousemove keydown scroll', function () {

        clearTimeout(idleTimer);

        idleState = false;

        idleTimer = setTimeout(function () { 

            // Idle Event
            var $carousel = $('.carousel').flickity()
            .flickity( 'select', 0 );

            idleState = true; }, idleWait);
    });

    $("body").trigger("mousemove");

});
```